# Pushing C++ function return values to OTcl in NS2

Tags: c++, tcl, ns2

Using NS2, I am trying to pull out node energy at a given time and use that value to perform other calculations. Via the internet, it is a pretty common thing to do. The method I have found to perform this task is to create a C++ function inside your routing protocol .cc and .h files. Using DumbAgent routing protocol, I have added the following code to dumb-agent.cc:

```cpp
//Add energy variable to constructor
DumbAgent::DumbAgent() : Agent(PT_PING) {
    energy = 0.0;
}
...
//Create the function to retrieve energy

double DumbAgent::get_energy(nsaddr_t addr) 
{
    Node* thisnode = Node::get_node_by_address(addr);
    double energy ;
    energy = thisnode->energy_model()->energy();
    return energy;
}
```

And in the .h header file:

```cpp
class DumbAgent : public Agent {
 public:
  DumbAgent();
  virtual int command(int argc, const char*const* argv);
  virtual void recv(Packet *p, Handler *h=0);
  void trace(char* fmt, ...);
  //Added by Sam 
  virtual double get_energy(nsaddr_t addr);
 protected:
  Trace *tracetarget_;
  PortClassifier *dmux_;
  //Added by Sam 
  double energy;
  Node *thisnode;
};
```

Using `make` everything compiles successfully. However, how do I access this value from my OTcl script? I expect something like:

```
$ns at 5.0 get_energy($node(1))
```

Do I need to do some sort of attach/connect on the nodes in the Tcl script? How do I get my C++ function value from my OTcl?

Thank you

Comment: I'd expect `$ns at 5.0 $node(1) get_energy ???` where the `???` is something (don't know what!) that becomes the `addr` argument…

Comment: Hints : 1. https://getch.wordpress.com/2011/02/08/obtaining-node-position-and-energy-dynamically-in-ns2/ .... 2. https://www.dropbox.com/s/j0gswsmsws2238o/NS2%3AGetting-node-position-and-energy__elmurod.net.html.gz?dl=0